# What is the opposite of a technical layperson?

Tags: single-word-requests, technical

I want to convey in my resume that I have provided technical documentation that is easily digestible not only by people familiar with the subject, but also by laypersons.

However, I cannot think of a concise string of words (or single word) to describe a "person familiar with the subject" in the context of information technology.

For example:

- Some work I did was communicating ideas and concepts not only to [my peers], but also to people who are unfamiliar with the jargon.

Comment: You're looking for a word to replace "my peers"? Like "co-workers"? Or people in your position in the industry? Is a person  "unfamiliar with the jargon" the "technical layperson" in the question title? And what do you mean by "technical"? Having a basic understanding of computing and software technology? Having a "superuser's" understanding of it?  I am finding your question unclear in a number of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first word that comes to mind is **expert**. From
[The American Heritage® Dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/expert) on Wordnik:

> A person with a high degree of skill in or knowledge of a certain subject.

Comment: But noy IT-specific.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth An IT-specific word was not requested. The question said that the word will be used in that context, but did not ask that the word be specific to the context.

Comment: 'a concise string of words (or single word) to describe a "person familiar with the subject" in the context of information technology' would then boil down to 'a list of synonyms for _specialist_', hardly a suitable topic for ELU (though doubtless addressed before). And notice that OP's title question is 'What is the opposite of a technical layperson?' not 'What is the opposite of a layperson?'.

Comment: Since the OP did mention "concise string of words", in my circles we talk about SMEs - Subject Matter Experts.

Comment: My experience is the same as @user888379. SME for Subject Matter Experts is very much the norm for software development and tech support, at least in the US.

Comment: In Australia I have never come across the abbreviation SME. I would have assumed it could be applied to experts in whatever field was currently under discussion, though perhaps referring to knowledge, and not to skill. The only other antonyms of "layperson" I know of are synonyms of "priest" or "doctor", both of which are inapplicable here. Online thesaurus searches give informal synonyms for "expert", which are unlikely to meet OP's need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word “specialist” in that context.  I would myself prefer “technician” but that is often misunderstood to mean someone who assists a more senior scientist or expert, as in “lab technician”.

Answer (score 0):

A possible plural word is *cognoscenti*, meaning “people with a lot of knowledge about a particular subject”. See [cognoscenti](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cognoscenti). The singular, *cognoscente* is not common in my experience. It is not specific to information technology, in fact it is more commonly used in the arts, but it can be used generally.